# What is this racing game on a snowy road with traffic?

Tags: game-identification

I saw this video on Instagram a few days ago and I can't seem to find any response to identifying this game. It doesn't seem to have any identifiable HUDs. I'm not even sure if it is a racing game or a modded game.

Comment: Note: if you come across another video on Instagram next time, you can also directly link the Instagram video URL.

Comment: It's actually on Tumblr.com; it was more convenient for me to just take a video and do it mobile to Stack Exchange app.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because the video is dead ([relevant meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/how-should-a-game-identification-question-that-no-longer-has-a-valid-artifact-be/15517#15517))

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe this is the game called [*The Crew*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crew_(video_game)).  In this game, your drive across all of America (it's a fairly large map and it's also misshapen some), so you can encounter snowy regions like this.  It is similar to Forza Horizon.

The way I can tell is if you look closely at the video, you'll see around the edge of the screen a bunch of arrows moving around that indicate other players in the game.  This is the biggest indicator of the game. Take a look at this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot from the Crew]

I've circled the the arrows. The screenshot was pulled from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FofcMIzoxA).  Here is a screenshot from your video with the arrows also circled:

[image: Screenshot from video]

Other things as evidence is I believe the car being driven is a Ferrari 458.  It has a twin exhaust which you can make out in your video (circled in the screenshot):

[image: Exhaust from Video]

As you can see in the below screenshot, it shows the exhaust (as well as the other similar body features):

[image: Ferrari 458]

<sub>Screenshot from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDPQJpzwAQc).</sub>